# heroku node.js tutorial - send env variables to other js pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, express, environment-variables

so i'm in the process of doing the '[getting started](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#introduction)' on the heroku page.

by cloning their tutorial repo, i have decided to add my own `index.html` and `app.js` files into the `/public` folder they already created for me.

directory looks like this:

```
node-getting-started repo folder
| node_modules folder
| public folder
| | app.js
| | index.html
| index.js
| package.json
| Procfile
```

the `package.json`'s `main` points to `index.js` which looks like this:

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    var obj = { ... };
    var secret_key = process.env.SECRET_KEY;
    // what should i do here to send the variables above to my app.js file?
    // response.send(secret_key) ???
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

at this point, what i'm trying to do is send that `obj` within the `index.js` to my `app.js` file so i can use it there.

is this is the right way to go about this? is there some other (proper?) way of sending it to the other file?

i would basically want to do the same thing with environment variables such as setting a `var secret_key = process.env.SECRET_KEY` in the `index.js` and sending it to the `app.js` so that i could use it there, too.

Could someone explain to me how I could go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you would like to keep the SECRET_KEY hidden from users, you can't send it to the client. In that case, you'll want to move the functionality that requires the key to the server.

For an API request that requires a key, have the client request to your server and the server will make the request to the API with the key. You'll want to modify the app.get route:

```
// '/api-request' will be the URI that the client uses
// the callback will handle what the server does when it receives a request with this URI
app.get('/api-request', function(req, res){

  request('API_URL' + process.env.SECRET_KEY, function(err, data) {

    // send error to the client -- res.send exits the function and ends the request
    if (err) res.send(err)

    // send data to the client
    res.send(data)
  })
})
```

Your server will act as a middleman to the API, keeping your key unexposed and contained to the server.

On the client, the request will receive whatever data the server sends back with res.send. Client has no idea there was a middleman involved.

```
// the browser is smart and knows that a leading / refers to the current domain
request('/api-request', function(err, data) {
  if (err) // handle error

  // do stuff with the data
  console.log(data)
})
```

Other operations that require a key can be handled in a similar manner. Your server will need a route to which the client will send a request with any relevant info and the server will send any resulting data.

Answer (score 1):

In order to pass varying data from the server to the page being viewed you need to *render* it. This is different from serving a static file.

Express supports different template engines such as Jade, EJS and Handlebars. Here's a quick example using little help from [express-generator](http://expressjs.com/starter/generator.html). First create example project by running

```
$ mkdir example
$ cd example
$ sudo npm install -g express-generator
$ express -e
```

Then in `routes/index.js` you can find the relevant part that renders view called *index* and passes a title along.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
```

The next part of your problem is to figure out howto pass data from your html to the `app.js` loaded in `<script>` element.